# I am unable to obtain list of elements from a class created in a python file to display in an HTML file

Tags: html, django, django-views, django-templates, pycharm

This is my `views.py` in which I have created the class `Pizza`.

```py
from django.shortcuts import render

from .models import Pizza


def index(request):

    pizzas = Pizza.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'menu/index.html', {'pizzas ': pizzas})
```

And this is the html file:

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Our Pizzas</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Our Pizzas</h1>
    <ul>
        {% for pizza in pizzas %}
            <li>{{pizza.name}}</li>
        {% endfor %}

    </ul>

</body>
</html>
```

In the result the page should have given me the names of pizzas stored in the class `Pizza` but it is giving me only what is inside `<h1></h1>` tags.

This is what I get:

[image]

When I inspect the html page it gives me this:

[image]

There is nothing between the `<ul>` and `</ul>` tags. Maybe it is unable to access elements from the class. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have copied your code and tried to reproduce the problem you're having, but I didn't encounter any problems.

Here is the code I used to replicate your problem:

**models.py**

```py
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse

class Pizza(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='none')
    ingredients = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='none')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("pizza_detail", kwargs={"pk": self.pk})
```

**admin.py**

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Pizza

admin.site.register(Pizza)
```

**views.py**

```py
from django.shortcuts import render

from .models import Pizza

def index(request):
    pizzas = Pizza.objects.all()
    context = {
        'pizzas': pizzas
    }
    return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

**index.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> {% load static %}
<html>
  <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <title>Stackoverflow-tests</title>
  </head>
 <body>
    <h1>Our Pizzas</h1>
    <ul>
        {% for pizza in pizzas %}
            <li>{{pizza.name}}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
 </body>
</html>
```

After doing all this, i created a superuser using `py .\manage.py createsuperuser`, after doing so i went to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/` and create a Pizza using the Pizza model registered in `admin.py`.

When i was done creating the pizza, i went back to the home-page (`index.html`) and the pizza was there.

While i do not know your problem specifically, you can use this code to compare it to your own and fix it yourself.

Images:
[image: django-admin-pizza]
(image-1)

[image: pizza-home-page]

(image-2)