# Unable to understand the bug in views.py

Tags: html, django, django-views, django-templates, pycharm

This is my `views.py` in which I have created the class `Pizza`.

```py
from django.shortcuts import render

from .models import Pizza


def index(request):

    pizzas = Pizza.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'menu/index.html', {'pizzas ':pizzas})
```

And this is the html file:

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Our Pizzas</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Our Pizzas</h1>
    <ul>
        {% for pizza in pizzas %}
            <li>{{pizza.name}}</li>
        {% endfor %}

    </ul>

</body>
</html>
```

In the result the page should have given me the names of pizzas stored in the class `Pizza` but it is giving me only what is inside `<h1></h1>`

[image]

When I inspect the html page it gives me this:

[image]

There is nothing between the `<ul></ul>`

When I run the debugger for the `views.py` file, it gives me:

> django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting INSTALLED_APPS, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.

Please suggest solution.

Comment: You added space in  {'pizzas ':pizzas}. It should be  {'pizzas' : pizzas}

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I am unable to obtain list of elements from a class created in a python file to display in an HTML file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76617625/i-am-unable-to-obtain-list-of-elements-from-a-class-created-in-a-python-file-to)

Answer (score 0):

The code looks pretty good to me.

```
return render(request, 'menu/index.html', {'pizzas ':pizzas})
```

In this line we have a space after 'pizzas' in context. Try removing it.

If that doesn't help, please share screenshot of the error.